# Compiling Multiple .tex Files in Directory with Subdirectories Simultaneously

Tags: compiling

First: I'm working on a Fedora 39 machine and I've converted all my documents to be compiled using the `lualatex` engine.

The heading says it all but here we go with my question: Is it possible to compile multiple `.tex` files in a directory with subdirectories simultaneously? If it is possible, how do I do what?

The reason I ask is that when the Tagged PDF Project is finished at some point, I would like to compile all my several hundred documents at once to get them up to date.

Comment: `for i in $(grep -rl '\\documentclass'); do pdflatex "$i"; done`

Comment: Would `latexmk` be more appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with bash you could do

```
for i in $(grep -rl '\\documentclass'); do pdflatex "$i"; done
```

which will run pdflatex on all files containing `\documentclass` (so you don't run pdflatex on individual input files for sections etc.)

Of course you can customise as required such as adding in bibtex or makeindex, or changing `pdflatex` to `lualatex`  or whatever you need. Also you could perhaps use `&` judiciously so the different runs happen in parallel hopefully using up separate cores on your machine.